# I want to run migration from PostgreSQL to sqlite3

Tags: django, database, migration

currently I am using PostgreSQL database in my project but I also want to use SQLite for localhost, so I want to run migrate command but there are errors because in SQLite array field is not used so I want to convert array field to JSONfield and makemigrations but in migrations old migrations also present. S I want to write custom logic in migrations. So, it use old migrations when database is PostgreSQL and new migrations when it is sqlite3.

I don't want create new migrations and migration table every time I switch databases.

Comment: I highly recommend that you DO NOT use different databases for each environment. Stick to PostgreSQL. And do not create new migrations. Read more about this [here](https://mrtnschndlr.medium.com/why-database-migrations-indicate-the-importance-of-quality-for-a-programmer-688b74f6802c). I've done the same mistake before in a personal project. I ran into production issues wherein my models are not compatible to PostgreSQL and it was frustrating to fix since my project already has migrations in SQLite.

Comment: Plus one for this.  I also suggest getting PostgreSQL running in your local development environment, using it exclusively.

Answer (score 0):

SQLite is more of a flat file system. I think the original idea is that you can store a small amount of data on a device and update the main database, or fetch info from a database, when the device is 'idle' as a background process. I know there may be some people putting this comment down but essentially SQLite is 'Light' and a flat file. Those considerations should be taken into account. btw I see that there is MYSQL for Andriod but I have not tried it out.